# Combine two querysets

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 2 querysets from 2 different models like this:

```
qs1=[[username1, lastname1, firstname1], [username2, lastname2, firstname2]........[username10, lastname10, firstname10]]
qs2=[[username1, email1], [username2, email2]...[username10, email10]]
```

I need to combine them to one and sorted by username. So it becomes like this:

```
qs=[[username1, lastname1,  firstname1, email1], [username2, lastname2,  firstname2, email2]...[username10, lastname10,  firstname10, email10]]
```

qs1 and qs2 are querysets with multiple entries.

I have code in view.py like this:

```
usernames = C.objects.values('username')
for username in usernames:
    try:
       qs1=A.objects.filter(username=username).values('username','lastname',' 'firstname')
       qs2=B.objects.filter(username=username).values('username','email')

qs = sorted(chain(qs1, qs2))
return qs
```

How do I combine qs1 and qs2 to qs?

Comment: Normally, django support Easy query like Model.Object.xxx. If you want to create some extra thing, i recomment you to use Raw query

Comment: will be more helpful if you post your model instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools`

```
from itertools import chain
result_list = list(chain(qs1, qs2))
```

Comment: Thank you! Chain works ok. However, why I am only getting last entry for qs? I tried to append or update qs, it did not work.

Comment: So qs = [username10, lastname10, firstname10, email10]. I need to get result of qs = [[username1, lastname1, firstname1, email1], [username2, lastname2, firstname2, email2]...[username10, lastname10, firstname10, email10]]